# Specify image size?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I have a document that has two images in it to demonstrate what I am talking about in the document. Both images needed to be shrunk from their original size, I would like them to be the same size but I can't seem to get it exactly right when resizing with the mouse. Is there any way to set the image size with a number that I could copy?

Comment: You'll probably be better off using a local image editing tool to make both of your source images the same size before inserting them into your document.

Comment: @AlE. They are already the same size and I don't want them at any lower resolution since I expect the viewers will zoom in for more detail. (This document will only be viewed digitally)

Answer (score -1):

Try to find the object properties in your document when you have the image selected. In most programs, it should be possible to find the size and change it.
Would be good if you tell us what the document type is, and what kind of images, like jpg, png or ...?
That way more people can discuss how you can see the properties and with what program you can change it.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you tell how to find and change the size.

Comment: I can't find any thing that mentioned properties. I can find "image options" but it only adjusts things like brightness and contrast. You say "in most programs", do you have experience with this program/freature or are you just guessing?

Comment: This isn't "most programs"; it's about Google Docs. I'm afraid your generic answer isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: I do not see the reference to Goolgle Docs anywhere. And I had a hope that the original program would be mentioned. I sometimes download the document and then view/edit it with LibreOffice before uploading again,

Comment: Please note the tags used for this question: [tag:google-drive] and [tag:google-documents]. Tags are how questions are categorized and so you know what Web Apps is being referenced. See also: [What are tags, and how should I use them?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)